# Regular Expression, how to avoid a specific value?

Tags: regex

I have a number of integers of length 3, I want all values including 0 and 1, I have this regular expression [0,1]{3}

But I like to avoid the value 000, how?

RegEx is needed in PL/SQL Oracle implements POSIX regular expressions, which are a fairly limited subset of modern Perl-style regular expressions which means Negative lookahead (?!) is not supported

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

`(?!000)[01]{3}`

http://regexr.com?301c8

> Match:
>  111
>  010
>  001
>
> Dont Match:
>  000
>  123
>  0
>  11

I'm not sure if you want *any* 3 character integer or only those containing 0 and 1 (except 000) in which case:
`(?!000)\d{3}` might be what you're looking for.

---

Without using lookahead.

(only integer): `(00[1-9]|0[1-9]0|0[1-9]{2}|[1-9]00|[1-9]{3})`

(any 0 or 1):`(001|010|011|100|1{3})`

Comment: All values are of length 3, no values like 0, 00 or 1

Comment: RegEx is needed in PL/SQL Oracle implements POSIX regular expressions, which are a fairly limited subset of modern Perl-style regular expressions which means Negative lookahead (?!) Is not supported, you have another idea?

Answer (score 2):

Someone will post a solution with negative lookarounds, or some similar black magic, but I'll post here what I posted somewhere else: Regex are amazingly powerful, but the knack is knowing when you shouldn't use them - testing for a specific value should be done outside your regex. Testing for ranges or patterns of values should be done inside the regex.

Comment: -1 for "black magic", I would agree if you would have said don't test for a number range with a regex (what you included in the valid use of regexes!?) but excluding one special value is not a problem.